# No ethercard detected during debian installation

Tags: debian

I just installed debian on my old laptop. During the installation, I got
`no ethercard detected error` and skipped it. Now I can't connect to the internet. So how do I find the right driver for my laptop and install it? Can I connect to the internet if I plug in the internet cable directly to my computer?
https://i.ibb.co/9WMgBdN/20221003-210601.jpg